# Cannot resolve plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-site-plugin:3.12.1

Tags: spring, spring-boot, intellij-idea, intellij-plugin

How to resolve this problem?

```
Cannot resolve plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-site-plugin:3.12.1
```

Try to run Maven import with `-U` flag (force update snapshots)

Photo1:
[image]

Photo2:
[image]

Comment: Can you add more information to the question, and can you try to maven clean and then update the project and do the maven install

Answer (score 5):

@romanv-jb's answer worked for me.

For those not familiar with Maven:

1. Navigate to the location of the problem version of maven-site-plugin in your local .m2 repository.
   Ex: `${YOUR_USER_DIR}/.m2/repository/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-site-plugin/3.12.1/`
2. Delete `maven-site-plugin-3.12.1.pom.lastUpdated`
3. In IntelliJ, navigate to the Maven tool window tab and select "Reload All Maven Projects".

[Reload All Maven Projects referece pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KMxvr.png)

Executing `mvn clean install` from your projects root directory should work the same as step 3 but I'm just showing what I did to fix the problem with the specific maven-site-plugin version in the OP.

Comment: I am getting this error in IDEA v2023.3.5 Community Edition after creating a Kotlin hello-world. And there are no *.lastUpdated files in that directory. Only: _remote.repositories; maven-site-plugin-3.12.1.pom and maven-site-plugin-3.12.1.pom.sha1. My host OS is Windows, not *nix, but I guess, it is irrelevant for the issue.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that the dependency is declared correctly in `pom.xml` (which it seems to be) and your machine has access to a repository that has the plugin, check if you have `.lastUpdated` file(s) in your Maven Local.
This might be a known issue [IDEA-310629](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-310629).